# CSS print issue, title aligns right

Tags: css, printing, alignment

I have my CV page at https://abiusx.com/cv ,
I want to modify it so that when user wants to print, menus are not visible but headers are.

The problem is, on the printed page (PDF) the title (AbiusX) and subtitle are automatically aligned to the right of the page, and it is really annoying me.
No matter what I do with the css, it goes there on the print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this inside your @media print

```
h1.author { 
          text-align:center; 
          margin:auto; 
          margin-top:5px; 
}
```

Your css default media appears as screen when i check it with firebug and chrome developer tools, so i think when its processed to be printed the h1.author definition is omited.

the resulting @media print you should have is:

```
/* print media */
 @media print {
.noprint {
    display:none;
}
    h1.author {
        text-align:center;
        margin:auto;
        margin-top:5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why this is needed?

Comment: the media="all" option that you put is for another css file, not the one containing the tag description you need.
The css file containing the tag description is style.css and this hava a media="screen" option.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your css file

```
@media print
{
  //put here the css you want for printing.
}
```

For example you have a title with a .title class that dont want to show when you're printing. Then you have to do this in the @media print:

```
@media print
{
     .title{
            display: none;
      }
}
```

Here you can try to give you title and subtitle the format you want.

Comment: I have done so. In fact I have a noprint class that prevents anything from being printed, but other than that the old styles should reside on the content, since the default media is all, and not screen.

Comment: did you try to add a padding right or margin right in the media print with an !important at the end to your title tags?? (Overwrite your previously styles)

Comment: whats with the !important? i used padding and background color and float and alignment, but non worked

Comment: try to add this inside your @media print {}:

     h1.author {
 text-align:center;
 margin:auto;
 margin-top:5px;
     }

Comment: can you post this as a separate answer plz